# How can I count weekdays only when I am choosing two dates using DirectoryInfo().GetFiles?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, file, weekday

I am trying to find a function to use with the `DirectoryInfo().GetFiles` function to only count weekdays when I am looking for files in a date range.

The only function I found is

```
.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

which is incompatible with `fileInfos.Where`

```
DateTime d1 = DateTime.Now;
d2 = d1.AddDays(FileAgeYounger);
DateTime d3 = DateTime.Now;
d4 = d3.AddDays(FileAgeOlder);

if (subfolders == true & 
    FileExtension != null & 
    Fileprefix != null & 
    FileUseRelativeAgeOlder == true & 
    FileUseRelativeAgeYounger == false & CountWeekDays == true)
{
    FileInfo[] fileInfos = new DirectoryInfo(FolderLocation).GetFiles("*.*", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> files = fileInfos.Where((f) => f.Extension.Equals(FileExtension)
                                                      && f.Name.StartsWith(Fileprefix)
                                                      && f.CreationTime >= d3
                                                      && f.CreationTime <= d4);
}
```

Comment: can you do the Where clause first and then `.Count()` ? In your example, just do `files.Count()`

Comment: I added this at the end of the code`, fileInfos.Count((f) => f.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday); ` and it gave me an error `local error 'fileInfos' is already defined`

Comment: If you can't do in with LINQ, implement it the normal way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this code...

```cs
.Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

...`x` is a `FileInfo`, which doesn't have a `DayOfWeek` property.  Instead, you need to use whichever of the three `*Time` properties of `FileInfo` is appropriate; looking at the condition you passed to `.Where()` that appears to be `CreationTime`...

```cs
int count = files.Count(x => x.CreationTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.CreationTime.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

Alternatively, that code could be made to work by using [`.Select()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select) to retrieve just the desired `*Time` property...

```cs
int count = files
    .Select(f => f.CreationTime)
    .Count(x => x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Saturday && x.DayOfWeek != DayOfWeek.Sunday);
```

In this case, `x` is a `DateTime`.

Also, keep in mind the differences between the older [`GetFiles()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.getfiles) and the newer [`EnumerateFiles()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.io.directoryinfo.enumeratefiles)...

> The `EnumerateFiles` and `GetFiles` methods differ as follows:
>
> - When you use `EnumerateFiles`, you can start enumerating the collection of `FileInfo` objects before the whole collection is returned.
> - When you use `GetFiles`, you must wait for the whole array of `FileInfo` objects to be returned before you can access the array.
>
> Therefore, when you are working with many files and directories, `EnumerateFiles` can be more efficient.

`EnumerateFiles()` is well-suited for this kind of filesystem search/filtering, and, I think, generally the preferred method to use.